# Is the following correct?

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
A a = new A();
A.name = "name1";
list.Add(a);
a = new A();
a.name = "name2";
list.Add(a);
```

Will the list finally contains the two same A with name equals to "name2"?

How to make use of one variable to achieve this?

Comment: You probably mean `a = new A();` instead of `a = new (A);`. Also that's probably exactly what you are missing in your original code to make two different instances in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list will contain two different instances of Type A; one with a name  set to "name1", the other set to "name2".

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors, it should be:

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
A a = new A();
a.name = "name1";
list.Add(a);
a = new A();
a.name = "name2";
list.Add(a);
```

...but this would result in 2 A elements with different names in the list.

Why? Well the `a` variable points to a new `A` instance, that reference gets added to the list, then `a` points to a *new* reference with the new `A` you create the second time, then *that* reference gets added to the list...so the list ends up with 2 distinct object references in the end - to different `A` instances each with their own `name`.

Comment: @Cody - oops, left over from testing his syntax - it wasn't looking quite right in the question, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Hashset(of T)?  You made need to create an IComparer for your class but it should only add one when two objects are equal.

[MSDN Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)